# Counting consecutive 1's in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding consecutive bit string of 1 or 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304705/finding-consecutive-bit-string-of-1-or-0)

Is it possible to count, from left, consecutive 1's in an integer?
So: total number of consecutive set bits starting from the top bit.

Using only:

```
! ~ & ^ | + << >>
```

`-1`= `0xFFFFFFFF` would return 32

`0xFFF0F0F0` would return 12 (FFF = 111111111111)

No loops, unfortunately.

Can assume the machine:

1. Uses 2s complement, 32-bit representations of integers.
2. Performs right shifts arithmetically.
3. Has unpredictable behavior when shifting an integer by more
    than the word size.

I'm forbidden to:

1. Use any control constructs such as if, do, while, for, switch, etc.
2. Define or use any macros.
3. Define any additional functions in this file.
4. Call any functions.
5. Use any other operations, such as &&, ||, -, or ?:
6. Use any form of casting.
7. Use any data type other than int.  This implies that you
    cannot use arrays, structs, or unions.

I've looked at 
[Finding consecutive bit string of 1 or 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304705/finding-consecutive-bit-string-of-1-or-0)
It's using loops, which I can't use. I don't even know where to start.

(Yes, this is an assignment, but I'm simply asking those of you skilled enough for help. I've done pretty much all of those I need to do, but this one just won't work.)

(For those downvoting simply because it's for school:
FAQ:
1 a specific programming problem, check
2 However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.)

Comment: How about walking the bits from left to right (or R -> L) if the bit at the current place is '1' do some action, if it is '0' do some other action?

Comment: For a second I was tricked by this: "For those downvoting simply because it's for school: FAQ" =))))

Comment: This seems sort of trivial, so unless you give us a clue where you're stuck, it's hard to think of a constructive answer. I could just write a couple of sample solutions, of course.

Comment: It is OK to ask assignment questions as long as you include what you've tried and explain which portion you need help with. See [How to ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812)

Comment: yes, because it is asking for consecutive 1's not total.

Comment: Would it have to be portable, or can we assume two's complement?

Comment: two's complement can be assumed.

Comment: Why do you need to count from the left ? The largest no of consecutive 1s will be the same whichever direction you count from, no ?

Comment: ah, is it the _total number of consecutive set bits starting from the top bit_? Not the longest run of set bits?

Comment: Yes Useless, I'll word it better.

Comment: OK - so you just need to find the most significant 0 bit ?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, and then count the 1'n "above" that. That actually clarifies things. My heads been going in circles these last few days.

Comment: FWIW, this is a _terrible_ assignment IMO.

Comment: @Zanii Did I get you correctly that constants greater than 0xFF are forbidden?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
int result = clz(~x);
```

i.e. invert all the bits and then count leading zeroes.

`clz` returns the number of leading zero bits (also commonly known as `ffs` or `nlz`) - see here for implementation details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Algorithms

Comment: Surely this is just the equivalent of counting the number of leading ones? Which will not give the correct result if the 'consecutive ones' appear anywhere other than at the start of the int.

Comment: @Lee: the question was somewhat ambiguous as originally worded but it seems that the OP does actually want the number of leading 1s - see the later comments under the question.

Comment: Ok, I read it as being the longest run of bits, but I see he has reworded it now.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are. The function argument may be signed or unsigned. The alg is independent on signedness.

```
int leftmost_ones(int x)
{
    x = ~x;
    x = x | x >> 1 | x >> 2 | x >> 3 | x >> 4 | x >> 5 | x >> 6 | x >> 7 | 
        x >> 8 | x >> 9 | x >> 10 | x >> 11 | x >> 12 | x >> 13 | x >> 14 | 
        x >> 15 | x >> 16 | x >> 17 | x >> 18 | x >> 19 | x >> 20 | x >> 21 | 
        x >> 22 | x >> 23 | x >> 24 | x >> 25 | x >> 26 | x >> 27 | x >> 28 | 
        x >> 29 | x >> 30 | x >> 31;
    x = ~x;
    return (x & 1) + (x >> 1 & 1) + (x >> 2 & 1) + (x >> 3 & 1) + (x >> 4 & 1) + 
        (x >> 5 & 1) + (x >> 6 & 1) + (x >> 7 & 1) + (x >> 8 & 1) + (x >> 9 & 1) + 
        (x >> 10 & 1) + (x >> 11 & 1) + (x >> 12 & 1) + (x >> 13 & 1) + (x >> 14 & 1) +
        (x >> 15 & 1) + (x >> 16 & 1) + (x >> 17 & 1) + (x >> 18 & 1) + (x >> 19 & 1) +
        (x >> 20 & 1) + (x >> 21 & 1) + (x >> 22 & 1) + (x >> 23 & 1) + (x >> 24 & 1) +
        (x >> 25 & 1) + (x >> 26 & 1) + (x >> 27 & 1) + (x >> 28 & 1) + (x >> 29 & 1) +
        (x >> 30 & 1) + (x >> 31 & 1);
}
```

A version with some optimization:

```
int leftmost_ones(int x)
{
    x = ~x;
    x |= x >> 16;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 1;
    x = ~x;

    return (x & 1) + (x >> 1 & 1) + (x >> 2 & 1) + (x >> 3 & 1) + (x >> 4 & 1) + 
        (x >> 5 & 1) + (x >> 6 & 1) + (x >> 7 & 1) + (x >> 8 & 1) + (x >> 9 & 1) + 
        (x >> 10 & 1) + (x >> 11 & 1) + (x >> 12 & 1) + (x >> 13 & 1) + (x >> 14 & 1) +
        (x >> 15 & 1) + (x >> 16 & 1) + (x >> 17 & 1) + (x >> 18 & 1) + (x >> 19 & 1) +
        (x >> 20 & 1) + (x >> 21 & 1) + (x >> 22 & 1) + (x >> 23 & 1) + (x >> 24 & 1) +
        (x >> 25 & 1) + (x >> 26 & 1) + (x >> 27 & 1) + (x >> 28 & 1) + (x >> 29 & 1) +
        (x >> 30 & 1) + (x >> 31 & 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to study this and try to use as few operators as possible. Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. The tricky part is to leave only ones that we like to count. The expression in return statement is just a sum of all bit values in the 'cleaned up' argument

Comment: Hmm, downvoter, could you please explain your reasons to give -1? The solution satisfies all restrictions in the question and produces correct result. It's hard to read, or it's hard to understand the logic?

Comment: I know this is possible with fewer ops. But I've got NO idea how.

Comment: You asked for a solution, but you did not ask for an optimal solution)

Comment: I know. Just sort of asking/thinking "outloud".

Comment: )) You made me thinking on your assignment again... I will share if I find more elegant solution

Comment: You managed to take 50 ops of it. Well done. Better then what I could do. Thank you once again!

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer for the return statement.

Comment: @ivo unfortunately no, as Zanii says that he can't use constants greater than 0xFF if I got him correcty

Comment: @Serge fair enough, but you can still do the same thing four times to get the bits for each byte :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a loop?

```
int mask = 0x80000000;
int count = 0;
while (number & mask) {
    count += 1;
    mask >>= 1;
}
```

Comment: No loops. Although that would have been grate.

Comment: @Johnny fix 0x8000 and remove the test (mask != 0). When you shift out its value completely the first test fails, so the loop terminates

Comment: @Serge. You're right. When mask == 0, (number & mask) will fail.

Comment: then fix 0x8000 - it should be 0x80000000

Answer (score 1):

I think it's doable, by basically unrolling the typical loop and being generally annoying.

How about this: an expression that is 1 if and only if the answer is 1? I offer:

```
const int ok1 = !((number & 0xc0000000) - 0x800000000);
```

The `!` and subtraction are to work around that someone broke the `==` key on our keyboard, of course.

And then, an expression that is 1 if and only if the anwer is 2:

```
const int ok2 = !((number & 0xe0000000) - 0xc0000000);
```

If you continue to form these, the final answer is their sum:

```
const int answer = ok1 + ok2 + ... + ok32;
```

By the way, I can't seem to remember being given these weirdly restricted assignments when I was in school, I guess times have changed. :)

Comment: I can't use "-" or numbers bigger then 0xFF so I'll have to say: 
!((number & (1<<31)) + ~(1<<31));, but I will try this.

Comment: @Zanii D'oh, forgot about the subtraction. Didn't know about the literals. Giving up on this, random restrictions on programming is ... not very helpful, it's like walking in a minefield. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a good way to get you to understand bitwise operators, but it's also a good way in making simple things as hard as can be.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count_consecutive_bits(unsigned int x) {
    int res = 0;
    while (x & 0x80000000) { ++res; x <<= 1; }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: should be 'x <<= 1' instead of 'x >> 1'

Comment: Whoops, wrong clipboard content -.-