# Algo for finding continuous items in log(N) time

Tags: c++, algorithm

Does anyone have a concise answer for this below? I saw this on career cup. http://www.careercup.com/question?id=4860021380743168

Given a binary representation of an integer say 15 as 1111, find the maximum longest continuous sequence of 0s. **The twist is it needs to be done in log N.**

For example. 10000101 
the answer should be 4, because there are 4 continuous zeroes.

If you have an answer in c++ that would be best for me

Comment: What is N? The number of bits in the integer? Or the integer value itself?

Comment: I think that is where my confusion lies as well.. this seems like the question is not well formed.

Comment: @Kaz: Who cares what "N" is -- if you want to sound smart in meetings, on forums or at parties, just throw "Oh-of-En" at everyone you see -- after all, if you sound computersciencey enough, who'd ask for details? Now let me make dinner, I usually do that in O(N).

Comment: @KerrekSB While you make dinner in order N, I will just ... order in.

Comment: I saw what you did there, @Kaz - and I approve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty trivial, just go through the binary notation, one linear pass. The binary notation has length `log(N)`, so it will take `log(N)` time.

Comment: What?? Five upvotes for such a super-trivial answer?? I have hundreds of others, very laborous answers here which didn't get a single upvote! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304705/finding-consecutive-bit-string-of-1-or-0/3311489#3311489).

However, when I feel the need for bit-twiddling, I reach for my copy of the incomparable [Hackers Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/).  As it turns out, it contains discussions on [finding the longest string of 1 bits](http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/fmaxstr1.c.txt), including a "logarithmic" implementation that could be used here on the bit/flipped (not) input:

```
int fmaxstr0(unsigned x, int *apos) {
   // invert bits.
   x = ~x;

   unsigned x2, x4, x8, x16, y, t;
   int s;

   if (x == 0) {*apos = 32; return 0;}
   x2 = x & (x << 1);
   if (x2 == 0) {s = 1; y = x; goto L1;}
   x4 = x2 & (x2 << 2);
   if (x4 == 0) {s = 2; y = x2; goto L2;}
   x8 = x4 & (x4 << 4);
   if (x8 == 0) {s = 4; y = x4; goto L4;}
   x16 = x8 & (x8 << 8);
   if (x16 == 0) {s = 8; y = x8; goto L8;}
   if (x == 0xFFFFFFFF) {*apos = 0; return 32;}
   s = 16; y = x16;

L16: t = y & (x8 << s);
     if (t != 0) {s = s + 8; y = t;}
L8:  t = y & (x4 << s);
     if (t != 0) {s = s + 4; y = t;}
L4:  t = y & (x2 << s);
     if (t != 0) {s = s + 2; y = t;}
L2:  t = y & (x  << s);
     if (t != 0) {s = s + 1; y = t;}
L1:  *apos = nlz(y);
   return s;
}
```

Have fun!