# Length of the longest consecutive 1's in a binary number

Tags: bit-manipulation, boolean-logic, binary-data, digital-logic

I need to implement a digital logic circuit with logic gates such as AND, OR, NOT, ADDER (and so on..), that gets an 8 bits binary number and return the number of the longest consecutive 1's in the input.

For example:

11110011 - will return 4

10101111 - will also return 4

01111111 - will return 7

I would really appreciate some help, as I'm struggling for days to find solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding consecutive bit string of 1 or 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304705/finding-consecutive-bit-string-of-1-or-0)

Answer (score 0):

I generated a truth table with 256 terms and reduced it to 47 terms using the [Espresso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer) minimizer:

[image]

Then, I converted the compressed table into a multi-level [circuit](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wCRcvB1X9x0ojCRuRVBprFWx2XMJ3nVO) (too big to be displayed here as image). For this, I used [Logic Friday 1](https://logic-friday.software.informer.com/1.1/).

It might be possible to derive a simpler circuit by mapping my C# routine into gates:

```
private static int countConsecutiveBits(int i)
{
    int bMax = 0;
    int b = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        if (((i >> j) & 1) == 1)
        {
            b++;
            if (bMax < b)
            {
                bMax = b;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            b = 0;
        }
    }

    return bMax;
}
```

This would involve adders and comparators as indicated in your question.

The following circuit - hand crafted and not verified - is a bit-slice which takes as inputs the so-far maximum bit count, the current bit count and the respective bit. The outputs are the new maximum bit count and the current bit count. All counts are 4-bit wide. This could be optimized for the first slices, where the count is smaller.

[image]